# Strange JSON API response SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, swift, http, post

I am sending an HTTP POST request to an API in swift and it is supposed to respond with:

```
    {
      "results": [
        {
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "transcript": "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge",
              "confidence": 0.98267895
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

However, I am receiving this through the print(jsonResponse) function:

```
Optional({
    results =     (
                {
            alternatives =             (
                                {
                    confidence = "0.9688848";
                    transcript = "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge";
                }
            );
        }
    );
})
```

Is there any reason why the response is not arriving in the correct format as indicated in the API documentation? I need to Decode the response to obtain the "transcript" value. However, I am receiving the following error:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "transcript", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"transcript\", intValue: nil) (\"transcript\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Maybe my request isn't optimal... Here's my code, any help is appreciated!

```
let parameters = ["config": ["encoding": "FLAC", "sampleRateHertz": "16000", "languageCode": "en-AU"], "audio": ["uri":"gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"]]

guard let url = URL(string: "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=AIzaSyDqYpPQIabwF5L-WibBxtVsWRBrc8uKi4w") else {return}

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

do {
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data , response , error) in

    guard let data = data else {return}

    do {
        let jsonResponse = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []))
        print("\(jsonResponse)")

        let course =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Course.self , from : data)
        print(course.transcript)       
    } catch {

        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

Here is my Course code block: Do I need to include the other components in the struct as well as the transcript?

```
struct Course: Decodable {
    let transcript: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case transcript = "transcript"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also paste code from Course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonResponse` is an Optional Dictionary, and thus that's why it's debug `description` looks like what you printed rather than pure JSON as you were looking for. Your problem likely is that your `Decodeable` objects are not properly setup - as by the looks of it you only have one `Course`. You'll likely need two more `Response` which contains a list of `Alternative`s. And then in `Alternative` you have a list of `Course`s.

Structure your objects like this, and it should do the trick:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let results: [Alternative]
}

struct Alternative: Decodable {
    let alternatives: [Course]
}

struct Course: Decodable {
    let transcript: String
    let confidence: Float
}
```

And then swap this line:

```
let course =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Course.self , from : data)
```

With this change:

```
let course = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data).results[0].alternatives[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! Yep, you solved a problem in a couple of minutes that not even 3 hours of googling could do for me! I am curious though, are the other structs (substructs if you will) required to follow the JSON hierarchy of the API response?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes they are necessary with how Decodable works.